# Can a module be viewed as a functor?

Tags: category-theory, modules

A monoid action can be viewed as a functor from $\textbf{M}$ to $\textbf{Set}$ which is constant if $\textbf{M}$ is the monoid. Knowing that a vector space is a group action of a ring $A$ on a group $E$, is there a way to :

- Interpret $A$ as a category $\textbf{A}$ ?
- Interpret the vector field $E$ as a functor (for example from $\textbf{A}$ to $\textbf{Grp}$ which is constant) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, a ring with identity is the same as a category enriched over $\bf Ab$ with one object.
2. A left [resp. right] module over a ring $A$ is the same as a functor between $\bf Ab$-enriched categories, from $A$ [resp. $A^{op}$] to $\bf Ab$.